# UWP Windows Phone detect type of USB connection

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-phone, usb, windows-10-mobile

I'm writing an app for a Windows 10 Mobile Enterprise phone, using the UWP framework and C#.

When I plug the phone into a computer, the phone prompts for whether I want to allow a data connection, or just power.

I know there's an event to detect whether the phone is being charged or not, but I need an event that is fired when the user says Yes to allow a data connection.

Comment: This may help you : https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/DeviceEnumerationAndPairing

Comment: I have previously played with that example, but I could never get the phone to see the computer as a Device from its point of view.

Comment: @tj94 did you mean the UWP app is running on the phone, and when the phone is connectting to the computer, you want the app to get notified?

Comment: Yes that's right